# PHPMailer not working on 000webhost

Tags: php, email, xampp, phpmailer

This code seems to work in Xampp on my mac localhost but it doesn't seem to work on my free 000webhost account. I already tried getting rid of SSL but it didn't help. Keep in mind that this program get variables from an external form.

```
 <?php
    $subject = htmlentities($_POST['subject']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);




    require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $m = new PHPMailer;

    $m->isSMTP();
    $m->SMTPAuth = true;
    //$m->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $m->Username = 'email-adress@gmail.com';
    $m->Password = 'password';
    $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $m->Port = 465;

    $m->From = 'email-adress@gmail.com';
    $m->FromName = 'William Green';
    $m->addReplyTo('email-adress@gmail.com', 'William Green');

    //$m->addCC('email2-address@gmail.com', 'Willliam green');


    ########################################
    //email code
    //$recipient = strip_tags($_POST['mailRecipient']);
    //$name = strip_tags($_POST['recipientsName']);


    $m->addAddress($email, $email);



    //$m->Subject = strip_tags($_POST['mailSubject']);
    //$m->Body = strip_tags($_POST['mailBody']);
    $m->Subject = $subject;
    $m->Body = $message;


   //$m->AltBody = 'plain text version!';


    ###########################################





    //var_dump($m->send());
    if ($m->send())
    {
    echo '<h1 class="good">Email Sent!</h1>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<h1 class="bad">Email Not Sent!</h1>';
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: 000webhost isn't that good when dealing with websites; their servers might be in a blacklist or they could be blocking outgoing SMTP ports to prevent spam. Perhaps it's time to move to a better web host, or you can save time and get yourself a Virtual Private Server to host your needs without restrictions.

Comment: You could try TLS on port 587.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *"but it doesn't seem to work on my free 000webhost account"*

**A:** They do **not** offer SMTP for free hosting. Use PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function instead.

Notice the red `x` next to SMTP Server on their site => http://www.000webhost.com/ ?

[image]

Either use [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) or **pay** for it in order to use SMTP.

You can do it on their website, or upgrade from within the control panel.

**Edit** (Sept. 16, 2016): This answer was posted before they revamped their website. The URL where you can see the available options for free/paid services, can be see here https://www.000webhost.com/premium-web-hosting

This also goes for remote connections to a database.

This answer was edited in regards to a question I saw today which was related to my edit.

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/39541929/1415724

Comment: I noticed that they have support for imap though. Could I somehow use imap instead of smtp. I'm not to familiar with the whole email thing.

Comment: Could you post some code that uses imap to connect? Very grateful! :D :-)

Comment: This page http://docs.ongetc.com/?q=content/which-email-service-available-000webhost is what I found on the subject and will explain it better. @www139 also in their forum http://www.000webhost.com/forum/announcements/4242-webmail-pop3-imap-enabled.html

Comment: I'm sorry when I posted this question I didn't know that phpmailer used smtp and I didn't even know what smtp was/is. Thank you for making it clear.

Comment: Hey Fred. It looks like [recently SMTP is being offered by this host](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/website-cannot-send-emails/73462), using Sendmail. I'm working on how to connect to it...

Comment: @halfer It always did, for paid hosting that is. See the comparison list https://www.000webhost.com/premium-web-hosting and under: **Email features** ;-) It's "x"d out for the "Free" version.

Comment: Yes, I think you might be right. It seems this is a question of language - the free account does seem to support email sending, but it has to be via the local `sendmail` binary (which of course does use SMTP internally). They don't offer an SMTP server themselves for free customers. However, my guess is they are fine with external SMTP providers such as GMail. Unfortunately SwiftMailer doesn't seem to work here, since that needs `proc_open`, and 000webhost have switched that off. Will try PHPMailer next!

Comment: Incidentally, I wonder if it is best to advocate that `mail()` is not used at all - use either Sendmail or direct SMTP. It looks like some serious vulns have come about as a result of using the PHP func directly, and SwiftMailer has stopped supporting it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the 465 port is open. If not, the host provider need to change the settings.

Comment: or could you try another port?